# SQLite CREATE TABLE errors

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

**UPDATE : The app now works again, however, it does not remember the information I want it to remember when I close it, which was the entire point of making the SQlite database. E.g. when I enter a homework task, and I close the app, it disappears and I have to re-enter it.**

I am following video tutorials on youtube (these videos, from 8-11 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKuM3cHO7G8&index=9&list=PL_PaSTBkUwk4PXlhZIe4COpwnWeCRnw2F ) to create a database in SQLite in Android Studio for one of my activities of an application for a school project.

However, when I run this application, when I attempt to navigate to this activity with the database, I get an error in the logcat. I cannot find a solution to this.

How would I resolve this? My application was working perfectly until then and it's frustrating as it's due in next week.

Here is the GitHub link to my application, and within README.MD, I have provided the entire error that logcat gives me.

https://github.com/soc0t/EPQTestingNotWorking/tree/master

Edit: this is the 'caused by' part of the error.

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: duplicate column name: address (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE contacts(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT,phone TEXT,email TEXT,address TEXT,address TEXTimageUriTEXT)
```

Comment: Please include the logcat stacktrace and relevant parts of the code here in this SO question.

Comment: There yo go, in your create Table script you have 2 times the column address, also you are missing a coma between TEXT and imageUri

Comment: I have removed the extra 'KEY_ADDRESS +" TEXT,", but where do I put the missing comma?